# How do i make this code output a random image from the directory /app/eevee?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is my code:

```
const superagent = require("snekfetch");
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const random = require('random')
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
     if (!message.channel.nsfw) {
        message.react('');
        return message.channel.send({embed: {
                color: 16734039,
                description: "CO TY ROBISZ! TE ZDJENCIA SA TYLKO DLA DOROSLYCH! (idz na kanal NSFW)"
            }})
    }
    superagent.get('https://nekos.life/api/v2/img/ero')
        .end((err, response) => {
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      const allMyFiles = fs.readdirSync("/app/eevee")
      .setTitle(":smirk: Eevee")
      .setImage(random.choice(allMyFiles))
      .setColor(`RANDOM`)
      .setFooter(`Tags: eevee`)
      .setURL(random.choice(allMyFiles));
  message.channel.send(embed);
    }).catch((err) =>
             console.log(err))
             message.channel.send({embed: {
                color: 16734039,
                description: "Something is wrong... :cry:"
            }});
    
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "eevee",
    description: "Fajno zdjencia",
    usage: "eevee",
    type: "NSFW" 
}
```

How do I make the command display a random image from a folder, if that is not possible does anyone know any API similar to nekos.life but with customizable images?

Answer (score 4):

Using `Math.random()`:

```
const allMyFiles = fs.readdirSync('/path/to/dir/')
let myFile = allMyFiles[Math.floor(Math.random() * allMyFiles.length)]
```

Comment: @eclipsek20 replace `/path/to/dir` with `/app/eevee` and in your embed, `allMyFiles` with `myFile` for this code to work